# Can't fully round images on Safari

Tags: css

I can't make my images perfectly round on Safari using `border-radius`. What's wrong with my code?

HTML:

```
<div class="people_photo_wrap">
  <img class="people_photo" src="image.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.people_photo_wrap {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.people_photo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}
```

[image]

Comment: remove the border on the image?

Comment: Worked, thanks! I can accept your answer if you make one.

Answer (score 1):

Add the radius to the image. Should do the trick.

```
.people_photo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```